# NYC area users - join us to celebrate Steve Jobs' Birthday!

Tags: discussion

Come join Ask Different and [Dr. Brendan](http://drbrendan.com/) for a party to honor Steve Jobs on his birthday. The party will start around 3 pm EST, and will take place outside the flagship Apple Store in NYC (59th Street and Fifth Avenue).

There will be black turtlenecks, cupcakes, and dancers. For more information, see this [New York Post article](http://www.nypost.com/p/news/business/fans_day_fete_for_jobs_HQzFUcSxhYb531oFfG6kmJ) covering the event. This event was also [covered by CNBC](http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=3000075169) this morning, so we're hoping for a great turnout!

If you can't make it to the event, we will be live tweeting it from @StackApple, so follow along!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this seems more than a little exploitive of the memory of Steve Jobs.

Comment: @KyleCronin SJ's vision permeates tech culture and I prefer to celebrate this in a positive way!

Comment: @SethRogers I have no problem with people celebrating Steve Jobs in their own way, though in this case I think it's a bit tasteless. However, this is ostensibly a promotion for Stack Exchange - it was mentioned in the NY Post article and the CNBC interview; you even had a Stack Exchange shirt on. And that's what I object to - using the memory of Steve Jobs, who has only been dead a few *months* to promote the company and this site.

Comment: it's a birthday party for a visionary we all admired @KyleCronin. Point taken though. Thanks!

Comment: The CNBC interview is all about what big fans Seth and Brendan are of Steve Jobs - they only mention Ask Different to say where Seth is from. I think it's a very tasteful interview, and we don't intend for this to be an excuse for a promotion. But we do see your point Kyle. Don't want you to think we're being insensitive.

Comment: The Ask Different moderators weren't involved in advance of this promotion?

Comment: I'm not aware of any site users including the moderators that knew of this before the blog post went up. Of course the SE employees / CHAOS team and employees that printed up the balloons would be excluded.

Answer (score 7):

The party was a TON of fun! The cupcakes and turtlenecks set a really great vibe and there were a few dozen people who joined us for the event. SJ's memory was celebrated in such a positive way - people were all smiles reflecting on how SJ changed their lives personally or just how much they loved their Apple products.

Unfortunately is was raining and cold, so people were afraid of getting their devices wet (mostly iPhones and iPods). The cupcakes also got a bit wet. All in all though, it was a memorable and happy birthday party for all the SJ admirers who attended.

I know some people got a bad taste in their mouths about this party; I'm sorry for that. For me, the party was a fun way to remember a visionary we all looked up to and those who made it out through the rain and cold seemed to have a really great time too. I think their was certainly a problem in the communication of this event, it was written about and publicized in a way that could have obscured the true joy of the party.

Here's a snapshot taken from one attendee's iPhone: [image]

Comment: Very nice follow-up post! Thanks for posting a bit more about the event.